# Turn off RSVP on flask project

Tags: python, outlook, icalendar

I have problem with turning off rsvp

How it looks on outlook

[image]

my code

```
     cal = icalendar.Calendar()
    cal.add('prodid', '-//My calendar application//example.com//')
    cal.add('version', '2.0')
    cal.add('method', "REQUEST")
    cal.add('RSVP', 0) 
    event = icalendar.Event()
    for a in attendees:
     event.add('ATTENDEE', a)
    event.add('organizer', "test@test.com")
    event.add('RSVP', False)
```

i'm getting error like this

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\icalendar\prop.py", line 164, in __new__
    self = super(vBoolean, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'TRUE'
```

i'm try a lot of ways, i wanna turn off it
I'm writing true because https://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/rsvp.html in this documentation say default is false.
I try write 0 or 1 in like this    `event.add('RSVP', "1")` but not working too

with command `print(cal.to_ical().decode("utf-8"))` shows `RSVP` is false, but i'm still getting in outlook RSVP button

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//My calendar application//example.com//
METHOD:REQUEST
RSVP:FALSE
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:12312312312312312312312312\,
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20201030T070000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/London;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20201030T080000
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20201030T060000Z
UID:1231231234545646453245345345343
SEQUENCE:1
ATTENDEE:test@test.com
ATTENDEE:test2@test.com
CATEGORY:Event
CREATED;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20201013T130632Z
DESCRIPTION:asdasdadsssss
ORGANIZER:testtts@tesssst.com
PRIORITY:5
PRIORITY:5
RSVP:FALSE
STATUS:confirmed
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT1H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

in .isc file from outlook im getting line
`ATTENDEE;CN="Test";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:it.test@test.com`
but in my code it set false.

Please help me i'm stuck all help will be appreciated

Comment: It's quite hard to say because of the lack of context (like what library are you using, and what type is `event`, how did you create it, etc.?). But did you try using 1 or True instead of "1"? I would suspect it should be 0 or False, though, but that's kind of another issue.

Comment: ``` event = icalendar.Event()``` if u use just 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' im getting error. ```NameError: name 'FALSE' is not defined``` if u try use 1 instead of "1" im getting same stuff..

Comment: True is completely distinct from TRUE in Python. Only True is a built-in constant. TRUE is just an arbitrary undefined identifier. So you have to use True or False, with that exact capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

Using True or False makes the code work. You also need to add the event to the calendar.

Here is a full working example:

```
import icalendar

# Test data.
attendees=["Jim", "Susan", "Peter"]

cal = icalendar.Calendar()
cal.add('prodid', '-//My calendar application//example.com//')
cal.add('version', '2.0')
cal.add('method', "REQUEST")
cal.add('RSVP', 0)

event = icalendar.Event()
for a in attendees:
    event.add('ATTENDEE', a)
event.add('organizer', "test@test.com")
event.add('RSVP', False)

cal.add_component(event)

print(cal.to_ical().decode("utf-8"))
```

Output:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//My calendar application//example.com//
METHOD:REQUEST
RSVP:FALSE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE:Jim
ATTENDEE:Susan
ATTENDEE:Peter
ORGANIZER:test@test.com
RSVP:FALSE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Whether that then is interpreted correctly in Outlook I cannot check, as I don't have Outlook. I am also no expert in the iCalendar format. But the Python code works perfectly using True or False for RSVP.

If you are still having problems with importing the iCalendar into Outlook, then make an iCalendar file manually and see whether Outlook imports it as you expect. If it doesn't, it's most likely a problem with the iCalendar file.

When you know you have an ical file that imports correctly into Outlook, only then try to create that iCalendar file in Python.

Comment: thank you for help,  its nice command ```print(cal.to_ical().decode("utf-8"))``` in my case im getting log with RSVP false, but still in outlook show RSVP button.

Comment: You're welcome. And okay, then I recommend you try to manually craft a functioning ical file to figure out what the correct format is. You could also try to create a correct event in Outlook and then export that to ical format, to see what the correct format is. Note though that Outlook probably adds a lot of stuff you don't need and which could be Microsoft-specific. But of course others here could know more about the Ical format than me. I just focused on the Python problem. 

Comment: Thanks man, i know i'm still new in Outlook stuff and python im add in my question output maybe it will be help to solve the problem

Comment: in outlook isc file im getting ```ATTENDEE;CN="IT Support";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:test@test.com```

Comment: Yes, I suspected that from looking at other examples. So apparently that RSVP needs to be put in each attendee. I wonder if the icalendar module has an attendee class to help construct that.

Comment: i try to figure how to do it, im trying put it on cycle but still nothing. Searching on internet, but nothing found :(